# Installer.Install(IDictionary stateSaver) : What dictionary type is expected?

Tags: c#

I am trying to call [Installer.Install](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.install.installer.install.aspx) manually:

```
ProjectInstaller installer = new ProjectInstaller();
installer.Install(new Dictionary<int, int>());
```

Problem:

```
System.ArgumentException was unhandled.
The value "_reserved_lastInstallerAttempted" is not of type "System.Int32"
and cannot be used in this generic collection.
       at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowWrongKeyTypeArgumentException(Object key, Type targetType)
       at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.System.Collections.IDictionary.Add(Object key, Object value)
       at System.Configuration.Install.Installer.Install(IDictionary stateSaver)
       at CSShellExtContextMenuHandler.ProjectInstaller.Install(IDictionary stateSaver) in C:\Users\win7pro32bit\Documents\lab\CSShellExtContextMenuHandler\ProjectInstaller.cs:line 40
       at Starter.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\win7pro32bit\Documents\lab\Starter\Program.cs:line 14
```

As a parameter I tried `new Dictionary<int, int>`, `new Dictionary<string, string>`, and others, but none works. The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.install.installer.install.aspx) does not help. What is expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running the System.Configuration.Install.Installer class through .NET Reflector reveals the following internal implementation of the Install method:

```
public virtual void Install(IDictionary stateSaver)
{
    if (stateSaver == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(Res.GetString("InstallNullParameter", new object[] { "stateSaver" }));
    }
    try
    {
        this.OnBeforeInstall(stateSaver);
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        this.WriteEventHandlerError(Res.GetString("InstallSeverityError"), "OnBeforeInstall", exception);
        throw new InvalidOperationException(Res.GetString("InstallEventException", new object[] { "OnBeforeInstall", base.GetType().FullName }), exception);
    }
    int num = -1;
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
    try
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.Installers.Count; i++)
        {
            this.Installers[i].Context = this.Context;
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < this.Installers.Count; j++)
        {
            Installer installer = this.Installers[j];
            IDictionary dictionary = new Hashtable();
            try
            {
                num = j;
                installer.Install(dictionary);
            }
            finally
            {
                list.Add(dictionary);
            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        stateSaver.Add("_reserved_lastInstallerAttempted", num);
        stateSaver.Add("_reserved_nestedSavedStates", list.ToArray(typeof(IDictionary)));
    }
    try
    {
        this.OnAfterInstall(stateSaver);
    }
    catch (Exception exception2)
    {
        this.WriteEventHandlerError(Res.GetString("InstallSeverityError"), "OnAfterInstall", exception2);
        throw new InvalidOperationException(Res.GetString("InstallEventException", new object[] { "OnAfterInstall", base.GetType().FullName }), exception2);
    }
}
```

The stateSaver parameter seems to be getting passed a string,int KeyValuePair, and a string,IDicitionary[] KeyValuePair internally:

```
stateSaver.Add("_reserved_lastInstallerAttempted", num);
stateSaver.Add("_reserved_nestedSavedStates", list.ToArray(typeof(IDictionary)));
```

I'm not exactly sure how it's managing that. Maybe because they're initializing the IDictionary they pass to the base.Install method as a Hashtable?

```
IDictionary dictionary = new Hashtable();
```

Hopefully some of this can point you in the right direction.

Comment: You're welcome, glad it worked. .NET Reflector does its magic yet again!

Comment: A lot of WiX toolset code was written in NETFX v1.1 days so old collections classes are prevalent. :)