# Running a service installer inside main program

Tags: c#, service, installation

I have created three main services within my main program. I have made three System.Configuration.Install.Installer within my main program as well. What I am wanting to do if possible is to install my three services through my main program without having separate .exes for the services. Is this possible? What I was thinking was something like:

```
ServiceProjectInstaller installer = new ServiceProjectInstaller();
installer.Install(); //I don't know what to pass in a generic IDictionary that matches what the Install is looking for.
ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] { new MainService() };
ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
```

Would this approach work? I would prefer to remove as much complexity as possible.

Comment: Are you using a setup project (Visual Studio installer?) or just writing a program to install services?

Comment: It does way more than just installing the services and the installer is created using InstallShield.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15609509/installer-installidictionary-statesaver-what-dictionary-type-is-expected)

I ended up creating two dictionaries assigning them both to IDictionary dictionary = new Hashtable(); I made a method that calls the Install passing in the dictionaries. The service did install just fine.

```
public void Install()
{
     try
     {
         serviceInstaller1.Install(Dictionary);
         serviceProcessInstaller1.Install(ProcessDictionary);
     }
     catch
     {

     } 
}
```